# Grouping data by start and end date

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2016, row-number

I have a dataset of two kids who are to meet based on their placement.

[image]

Here is the desired output I am trying to get

[image]

I am trying to write a SQL query in (SQL Server 2016) using RowNumber to put a unique group number for each colored scheam so that I can use group by in next query to get start and end date but its not working

```
Select DISTINCT [Date], [Visitee Id], [Visitor Id], Group,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Visitee Id], [Visitor Id], Group ORDER BY [Visitee Id], [date], Group) AS GroupNumber

    FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  If you are interested only in consecutive days, you can handle this with `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select visiteeid, visitorid, group, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by visiteeid, visitorid, group order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by visiteeid, visitorid, group,
         dateadd(day, - seqnum, date);
```

The idea is that subtracting a sequence from a dates is constant when the dates increment by 1 on each row.  The rest is just aggregation.